# Derivation of Regularized Linear Regression Cost Function per Coursera Machine Learning Course

Tags: regression, self-study

I took Andrew Ng's course "Machine Learning" via Coursera a few months back, not paying attention to most of the math/derivations and instead focusing on implementation and practicality. Since then I have started going back to study some of the underlying theory, and have revisited some of Prof. Ng's lectures. I was reading through his lecture on "Regularized Linear Regression", and saw that he gave the following cost function:

$$J(\theta) = \frac{1}{2m}[\sum_{i=1}^m(h_\theta (x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2 + \lambda\sum_{j=1}^n\theta^2_j]$$

Then, he gives the following gradient for this cost function:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}J(\theta) = \frac{1}{m}[\sum_{i=1}^m(h_\theta (x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})x^{(i)}_j - \lambda\theta_j]$$

I am a little confused about how he gets from one to the other. When I tried to do my own derivation, I had the following result:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}J(\theta) = \frac{1}{m}[\sum_{i=1}^m(h_\theta (x^{(i)}) + y^{(i)})x^{(i)}_j + \lambda\theta_j]$$

The difference is the 'plus' sign between the original cost function and the regularization parameter in Prof. Ng's formula changing into a 'minus' sign in his gradient function, whereas that is not happening in my result.

Intuitively I understand why it's negative: we are reducing the theta parameter by the gradient figure, and we want the regularization parameter to reduce the amount that we are changing the parameter to avoid overfitting. I am just a little stuck on the calculus that backs this intuition.

FYI, you can find the deck [here](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/ml/docs/slides/Lecture7.pdf), on slides 15 and 16.

Comment: In your result you have a "**+**" preceding the y^(i)--is that a typo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually if you check the lecture notes just after the video , it shows the formula correctly .
The slides that you have lined here shows the exact slide of the video.

[image]

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/supplement/pKAsc/regularized-linear-regression here its the link to the notes right after the video showing correct formula.

Answer (score 14):

$J(\theta) = \frac{1}{2m}[\sum_{i=1}^m(h_\theta (x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2 + \lambda\sum_{j=1}^n\theta^2_j]$

Now

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}(h_\theta (x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2=2[(h_\theta (x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}\{h_\theta(x^{(i)})\}]$

Note that in a linear model (being discussed on the pages you mention), $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}(h_\theta(x^{(i)})=[x^{(i)}]_j$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}\lambda\sum_{j=1}^n\theta_j^2=2\lambda\theta_j$

So for the linear case

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}J(\theta) = \frac{1}{m}[\sum_{i=1}^m(h_\theta (x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})x^{(i)}_j + \lambda\theta_j]$

Looks like perhaps both you and Andrew might have typos. Well, at least two of the three of us seem to.

Comment: its confirmed, just a typo on the Andrew's note, it should be a + sign. And Prof correctly explain everything correctly including the intuition θ(1-α(λ/m)) meaning every time this shrink θ then minus the usual part before regularisation being introduced.

Comment: How does the derivative of the regularization term work out to 2λθj? I understand the power rule, but I'm not sure what happens to the inner function because I thought the ∑ notation would appear in the resulting derivative.

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = 2x$ ... why would you expect to see a sum involving the terms in $y$ and $z$?

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: To add more context on how ∑ goes off:

`(d/dw_j) Σ[j=1 to n] w_j^2 = (d/dw_j) (w_1^2 + w_2^2 + ... + w_j^2 + ... + w_n^2)
= 0 + 0 + ... + 2w_j + ... + 0
= 2w_j`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think that's just a typo.

On slide #16 he writes the derivative of the cost function (with the regularization term) with respect to theta *but it's in the context of the **Gradient Descent*** algorithm. Hence, he's also multiplying this derivative by $-\alpha$. Notice: On the second line (of slide 16) he has $-\lambda\theta$ (as you've written), multiplied by $-\alpha$. However, by the third line the multiplied term *is still negative* even though--if the second line were correct--the negative signs would've cancelled out.

Make sense?